# C# - Devexpress repositoryitemcheckedit multi check in 2 columns

Tags: c#, devexpress

I added 2 columns to my GridView with repositoryItemCheckEdit and then used the columnView.CustomUnboundColumnData event to enable multiple checks

[(using this example)](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_CustomUnboundColumnDatatopic%29)

This code works with 1 column but 2 columns causes a problem...If I check a box in the 1st column, the same row in column 2 will auto check. If I check another box (same problem with checking a box in  the 2nd column)
Like  this (only check in Column 1):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In unbound mode and handling the CustomUnboundColumnData event you are expected to capture the value coming into the cell via the event using IsSetData and maintain the value manually so it's available in the same event using IsGetData.

You'll have to maintain your own data backing store (like a `List<bool`>) for that column's value(s), as the Grid control will not maintain this value internally for unbound columns.

Clearly data binding is superior but this is how it hangs together in unbound mode.